# appending elements to an existing table in R

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have created a data.table with one column. this column represents names of cars that i possibly will get data for:

```
mydata <-mtcars[1:10,]
setDT(mydata, keep.rownames = TRUE)
mydataBase <- data.table (rn = mydata$rn,
                           mpg = as.numeric(),
                           cyl = as.numeric(),
                           disp = as.numeric(),
                           hp = as.numeric(),
                           drat = as.numeric(),
                           wt = as.numeric(),
                           qsec = as.numeric(),
                           vs = as.numeric(),
                           am = as.numeric(),
                           gear = as.numeric(),
                           carb = as.numeric())
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
mydataBase
                   rn mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
 1:         Mazda RX4  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
 2:     Mazda RX4 Wag  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
 3:        Datsun 710  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
 4:    Hornet 4 Drive  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
 5: Hornet Sportabout  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
 6:           Valiant  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
 7:        Duster 360  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
 8:         Merc 240D  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
 9:          Merc 230  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
10:          Merc 280  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA
```

then i run a series of complicated functions. The result of every run of this function gives me information about one car. I want this information to be appended to the already existing table `mydataBase`

```
function(){

# complicated calculations

return(car1)

}
```

every time the function is run it saves the calculations in this format:

```
car1 <- mydata[2,]
car1
              rn mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

so i am looking for a way how can i fill in the table such that `rn` matches and no new columns are produced ?

the desired outcome:

```
                   rn mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 1:        Datsun 710  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
 2:        Duster 360  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
 3:    Hornet 4 Drive  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
 4: Hornet Sportabout  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
 5:         Mazda RX4  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
 6:     Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
 7:          Merc 230  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
 8:         Merc 240D  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
 9:          Merc 280  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
10:           Valiant  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
```

The function is repeated multiple time, whereby in each run a different car is calculated. By the end of the process , almost all cars will have data available.

I tried using merge, but extra columns are created. any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling this function? Are you calling it in some form of loop?

Comment: the function is called multiple time, similiar to a loop. Every time the function is called, values for a car are calculated. My original idea was to "fill" the mydataBase table inside the function and use "<<-" to rewrite it in the environment, so next time when the function is called and values for another car are calculated, they can be written in in the already existing table ... so that after 7-8 iterations, almost all cars have values

Comment: but i still know which values do not have values, because they are NA

Comment: Can you fill all the `car` values together? Or you have to fill them one by one only?

Comment: i have to fill the one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the row number to update and `set` to update the row.

```
library(data.table)

mydata <- mtcars[1:10,]
setDT(mydata, keep.rownames = TRUE)
mydataBase <- data.table(rn = mydata$rn,mpg = NA_real_,cyl = NA_real_,
                          disp = NA_real_,hp = NA_real_,drat = NA_real_,
                          wt = NA_real_,qsec = NA_real_,vs = NA_real_,
                          am = NA_real_,gear = NA_real_,carb = NA_real_)

car1 <- mydata[2,]
set(mydataBase, match(car1$rn, mydataBase$rn), 
                names(mydataBase)[-1], as.list(car1[, -1]))

mydataBase

#                   rn mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1:         Mazda RX4  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# 2:     Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3:        Datsun 710  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# 4:    Hornet 4 Drive  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# 5: Hornet Sportabout  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# 6:           Valiant  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# 7:        Duster 360  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# 8:         Merc 240D  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# 9:          Merc 230  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
#10:          Merc 280  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
```